# Adding Basic Web Browser in an Android Music Application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, web, import

Hey fellow programmers,

I need some help trying to figure out why my web browser in my android application is crashing. Any help would be great. I will post my codes on the affected JAVA classes that is connected to the browser, technically its quite a big program with different classes. I'll also include the android manifest file. So the last checkup that I did was I tried opening it with my tablet under Jelly Bean but its still crashing.

This is the code for the webactivity class

```
package com.example.gamaraza;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class WebActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.weblayout);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.buttonUrl);;
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
}


}
```

Android Manifest would be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.gamaraza"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

  <compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

</compatible-screens>

<supports-screens android:resizeable="false"
              android:smallScreens="true"
              android:normalScreens="true"
              android:largeScreens="true"
              android:xlargeScreens="true"
              android:anyDensity="true"
              android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="240"
              android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="240"
              android:largestWidthLimitDp="320"/>
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/glauncher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.gamaraza.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity

        android:label="@string/app_name"

        android:name="com.example.gamaraza.CreditActivity" >

    </activity>

    <activity

        android:label="@string/app_name"

        android:name="com.example.gamaraza.DubActivity" >

    </activity>
    <activity

        android:label="@string/app_name"

        android:name="com.example.gamaraza.AboutActivity" >

    </activity>
    <activity

        android:label="@string/app_name"

        android:name="com.example.gamaraza.SettingsActivity" >

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".WebViewActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />

    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".WebBrowser" >
        </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Thank you in advance

UPDATE:

```
package com.example.gamaraza;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.gamaraza.R;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

class Mp3Filter implements FilenameFilter{
public boolean accept(File dir, String name){
    return (name.endsWith(".mp3"));
    }
}


public class DubActivity extends ListActivity {

Button buttonUrl;
ImageButton stopPlay, dub1, dub2, dub3, dub4, dub5, dub6, dub7, dub8, dub9, dub10, dub11, dub12, dub13, dub14, dub15, dub16;
Button recbtn, dubback, choosebtn;
private MediaPlayer do2n,do3n,do4n,do5n,do6n,do7n,do8n,do9n,do10n,do11n,do12n,do13n,do14n,do15n,do16n,do17n;
MediaPlayer mp, mediaPlayer, myPlayer;
MediaRecorder myRecorder, myRecorder2, myRecorder3, myRecorder4, myRecorder5;
private SeekBar seekBar;
private String outputFile = null;
ImageButton buttonPlayS;
private final Handler handler = new Handler();
private static final String SD_PATH = new String ("/sdcard/Music/");
private List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
private MediaPlayer mpl = new MediaPlayer();
private String recholder = "not";
private String recorder = "one";
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyy_");
String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH-mm-ss");
String strDate2 = sdf2.format(c2.getTime());



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.dublayout);

        outputFile = (SD_PATH) + "/gamaraza"+strDate+strDate2+".mp3";

        myRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        myRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
        myRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_WB);
        myRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);
        myRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);

        myRecorder2 = new MediaRecorder();
        myRecorder2.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
        myRecorder2.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_WB);
        myRecorder2.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);
        myRecorder2.setOutputFile(outputFile);

        myRecorder3 = new MediaRecorder();
        myRecorder3.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
        myRecorder3.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_WB);
        myRecorder3.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);
        myRecorder3.setOutputFile(outputFile);

        myRecorder4 = new MediaRecorder();
        myRecorder4.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
        myRecorder4.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_WB);
        myRecorder4.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);
        myRecorder4.setOutputFile(outputFile);

        myRecorder5 = new MediaRecorder();
        myRecorder5.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
        myRecorder5.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_WB);
        myRecorder5.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);
        myRecorder5.setOutputFile(outputFile);
        addListenerButton();
        longclick1();
        choosebtn = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.choosebtn);
        choosebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ListView lv = getListView();
                if(lv.isShown()){
                lv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mpl.reset();
                songs.clear();
                }else{
                    lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    longclick();
                }


            }});

        final Button click =(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonUrl);       
        click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                                            
               public void onClick(View v) 
                       {             
           Intent launchactivity= new Intent(DubActivity.this,WebBrowser.class);                               
           startActivity(launchactivity);                          
                         }
                          });    

    dub1 = (ImageButton) this.findViewById (R.id.dub1);
    dub1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.dub1) {
                    do2n = MediaPlayer.create(DubActivity.this, R.raw.m1);
                    do2n.start();
                    do2n.setLooping(true);
                }
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.dub1) {
                    if (do2n != null) {
                        do2n.stop();
                        do2n.release();
                        do2n = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    dub2 = (ImageButton) this.findViewById (R.id.dub2);
    dub2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.dub2) {
                    do3n = MediaPlayer.create(DubActivity.this, R.raw.m2);
                    do3n.start();
                    do3n.setLooping(true);
                }
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.dub2) {
                    if (do3n != null) {
                        do3n.stop();
                        do3n.release();
                        do3n = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    dub3 = (ImageButton) this.findViewById (R.id.dub3);
    dub3.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.dub3) {
                    do4n = MediaPlayer.create(DubActivity.this, R.raw.m3);
                    do4n.start();
                    do4n.setLooping(true);
                }
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.dub3) {
                    if (do4n != null) {
                        do4n.stop();
                        do4n.release();
                        do4n = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    dub4 = (ImageButton) this.findViewById (R.id.dub4);
    dub4.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.dub4) {
                    do5n = MediaPlayer.create(DubActivity.this, R.raw.m4);
                    do5n.start();
                    do5n.setLooping(true);
                }
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.dub4) {
                    if (do5n != null) {
                        do5n.stop();
                        do5n.release();
                        do5n = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    dub5 = (ImageButton) this.findViewById (R.id.dub5);
    dub5.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.dub5) {
                    do6n = MediaPlayer.create(DubActivity.this, R.raw.m5);
                    do6n.start();
                    do6n.setLooping(true);
                }
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.dub5) {
                    if (do6n != null) {
                        do6n.stop();
                        do6n.release();
                        do6n = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    dub6 = (ImageButton) this.findViewById (R.id.dub6);
    dub6.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.dub6) {
                    do7n = MediaPlayer.create(DubActivity.this, R.raw.m6);
                    do7n.start();
                    do7n.setLooping(true);
                }
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.dub6) {
                    if (do7n != null) {
                        do7n.stop();
                        do7n.release();
                        do7n = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    dub7 = (ImageButton) this.findViewById (R.id.dub7);
    dub7.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.dub7) {
                    do8n = MediaPlayer.create(DubActivity.this, R.raw.m7);
                    do8n.start();
                    do8n.setLooping(true);
                }
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.dub7) {
                    if (do8n != null) {
                        do8n.stop();
                        do8n.release();
                        do8n = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    dub8 = (ImageButton) this.findViewById (R.id.dub8);
    dub8.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.dub8) {
                    do9n = MediaPlayer.create(DubActivity.this, R.raw.m8);
                    do9n.start();
                    do9n.setLooping(true);
                }
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.dub8) {
                    if (do9n != null) {
                        do9n.stop();
                        do9n.release();
                        do9n = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    dub9 = (ImageButton) this.findViewById (R.id.dub9);
    dub9.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.dub9) {
                    do10n = MediaPlayer.create(DubActivity.this, R.raw.m9);
                    do10n.start();
                    do10n.setLooping(true);
                }
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.dub9) {
                    if (do10n != null) {
                        do10n.stop();
                        do10n.release();
                        do10n = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    dub10 = (ImageButton) this.findViewById (R.id.dub10);
    dub10.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.dub10) {
                    do11n = MediaPlayer.create(DubActivity.this, R.raw.m10);
                    do11n.start();
                    do11n.setLooping(true);
                }
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.dub10) {
                    if (do11n != null) {
                        do11n.stop();
                        do11n.release();
                        do11n = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    dub11 = (ImageButton) this.findViewById (R.id.dub11);
    dub11.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.dub11) {
                    do12n = MediaPlayer.create(DubActivity.this, R.raw.m11);
                    do12n.start();
                    do12n.setLooping(true);
                }
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.dub11) {
                    if (do12n != null) {
                        do12n.stop();
                        do12n.release();
                        do12n = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    dub12 = (ImageButton) this.findViewById (R.id.dub12);
    dub12.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.dub12) {
                    do13n = MediaPlayer.create(DubActivity.this, R.raw.m12);
                    do13n.start();
                    do13n.setLooping(true);
                }
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.dub12) {
                    if (do13n != null) {
                        do13n.stop();
                        do13n.release();
                        do13n = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    dub13 = (ImageButton) this.findViewById (R.id.dub13);
    dub13.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.dub13) {
                    do14n = MediaPlayer.create(DubActivity.this, R.raw.m13);
                    do14n.start();
                    do14n.setLooping(true);
                }
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.dub13) {
                    if (do14n != null) {
                        do14n.stop();
                        do14n.release();
                        do14n = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    dub14 = (ImageButton) this.findViewById (R.id.dub14);
    dub14.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.dub14) {
                    do15n = MediaPlayer.create(DubActivity.this, R.raw.m14);
                    do15n.start();
                    do15n.setLooping(true);
                }
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.dub14) {
                    if (do15n != null) {
                        do15n.stop();
                        do15n.release();
                        do15n = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    dub15 = (ImageButton) this.findViewById (R.id.dub15);
    dub15.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.dub15) {
                    do16n = MediaPlayer.create(DubActivity.this, R.raw.m15);
                    do16n.start();
                    do16n.setLooping(true);
                }
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.dub15) {
                    if (do16n != null) {
                        do16n.stop();
                        do16n.release();
                        do16n = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    dub16 = (ImageButton) this.findViewById (R.id.dub16);
    dub16.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.dub16) {
                    do17n = MediaPlayer.create(DubActivity.this, R.raw.m16);
                    do17n.start();
                    do17n.setLooping(true);
                }
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.dub16) {
                    if (do17n != null) {
                        do17n.stop();
                        do17n.release();
                        do17n = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });


}


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, final int position, long id){

    mpl.reset();
    buttonPlayS = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ButtonPlayStop);

    buttonPlayS.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            if(mpl.isPlaying()) {
                mpl.pause();
                buttonPlayS.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playbtn);
            }
            else {

                try {
                    mpl.setDataSource(SD_PATH + songs.get(position));
                    getListView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
                try {
                    mpl.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mpl.start();
                 seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.SeekBar01);
                 seekBar.setMax(mpl.getDuration());


                seekBar.setProgress(mpl.getCurrentPosition());

                startPlayProgressUpdater();
                stopPlay = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.recstop);
                stopPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        mpl.stop();
                        seekBar.setProgress(0);

                    }
                });
            buttonPlayS.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playbtn2);

            }
            }

    });

}
```

Dubactivity too big but you can just check the first part of it You'll be able to see there how I'm trying to make enter a web browser option on this activity

Comment: The activity is not defined in the Manifest. I mean your activity is called WebActivity and the most similar one in the manifest is called WebViewActivity

Comment: I will add my other activity file connected to that hold on